# How to run python 3.7 in Ubuntu if python 3.6 is already installed

Tags: python

I am trying to run python 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal with "python3" command but python3 is running python 3.6

[image]

Comment: Please check your python version with `apt list --installed | grep python`

Comment: I have python 2.7, python 3.6 and python 3.7

Comment: Please remove python3.6

Comment: I wanted to use both that's why I posted this question

Comment: Then, you can run python3.7 with its full path. `/usr/lib/python3.7/bin/ptyhon3`

Comment: Also, you can add alias for that

Comment: Just run it as e.g. `python3.7` thus providing exact version will start it.

Comment: python3.7 not working @simkus

Comment: run this command in terminal `ls /usr/bin/ | grep "python"` and it will show what version you have installed, if you will not see python3.7 listed there, then it is not installed and you need to install it first

Comment: But if you have installed python 3.6 / python 3.7 and it still doesn't work, I would suggest to uninstall both 3.6 and 3.7, then reinstall 3.7 first and check if it works, then install 3.6 version. This might help

Comment: @simkus not working and I want to use both

Comment: @KingStone python 3.6 is required for Ubuntu 18.04 to work. DO NOT remove it

Comment: @KingStone thanks. I already checked this somewhere that not to uninstall 3.6

Comment: Have you tried just running `python 3.7`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having to juggle between too many versions, try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) to manage multiple versions easily. Here's a [script](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) that makes installation easier

Comment: Why the downvote? pyenv is made exactly for this scenario!

Answer (score -1):

If you have Python 3.7 installed, then you may create symlink to it:

```
ln -s python3.7 python3
```

Comment: Bad idea if Ubuntu relies on python3.6 being "python3"

Comment: It actually is... Yet it exactly answers OP question - how to run p3.7 with p3 command...

Answer (score -1):

Check your python versions with `which python` in your terminal.

After which, if python 3.7 is not installed. Follow the steps listed [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to install it.

You can then follow the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120474/setting-python3-to-version-3-7-on-wsl) to change the symbolic link