# How to replace python version in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

Is there any way to replace python version in raspberry pi? I have python version 3.9 in my raspberry pi OS and I want to replace it with python 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I downgrade my version of python from 3.7.5 to 3.6.5 on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549829/how-do-i-downgrade-my-version-of-python-from-3-7-5-to-3-6-5-on-ubuntu)

Comment: You can install any version you like from here https://www.python.org/downloads/ and set your PATH to pick up the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

Just execute

```
sudo apt autoremove python    
sudo apt install python3.7
```

for reference: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#using-apt