# Jupyter Notebook doesn't detect Python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am currently trying to install `Tensorflow 1.15.0`, but my current Python version is 3.8.10 which doesn't support that version of `Tensorflow`. I installed `Python3.7` using the following command:

```bash
sudo apt install python3.7
```

And used these commands from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914761/jupyter-notebook-cant-find-modules-for-python-3-6):

```
pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

But when I run

```
!python3 --version
```

it still shows 3.8.10 and `Tensorflow 1.15.0` fails to install with the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

I am not willing to uninstall Python 3.8, because last time I did that it completely broke my OS and forced me to reinstall the entire thing. How do I solve this issue? I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: **try answer in this article [this question for downgrade python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549829/how-do-i-downgrade-my-version-of-python-from-3-7-5-to-3-6-5-on-ubuntu)**

Comment: maybe you should install `jupyter` in `Python 3.7` and - `pip3.7 install jupyter` -  use `python3.7 -m jupyter` to run it.

Comment: @omar I followed the tutorial but now jupyter gives me this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...` when trying to import any module although I already installed those modules.

Comment: if you install different version all library in newer version at most not showing, you should download the library all over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to uninstall `Python 3.8` from your system. If you just simply follow the steps mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link, you can successfully install `TensorFlow 1.15` with `Python 3.7` in your system.

Or you can follow the steps below:

1. **[Download](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) and install Anaconda**

(Please ignore this step if it is already installed in your system)

2. **Create a virtual environment with Python (python=3.7)**

> ```
> conda create --name tf python=3.7
> conda deactivate    #to deactivate the tf environment
> conda activate tf   #to activate the tf environment
> ```

3. **Install tensorflow**

> pip install tensorflow==1.15

4. **Open jupyter notebook** in the same virtual environment (tf) and run below command:

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> tf.__version__     #to check installed tensorflow version
> !python --version  #to check installed python version
> ```

You can also create a virtual environment and install `python` and `TensorFlow` through **Anaconda Navigator**.

For this, Please open **Anaconda Navigator** and go to:

Environments -> create -> Vir_env name -> select Python  -> install and launch jupyter in the same Vir_env -> install required tensorflow version using code - `!pip install tensorflow==<version>`

Likewise, you can create multiple virtual environments and can install different compatible versions of python and tensorflow inside the same Anaconda Navigator.