Could not build wheels for cchardet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I would like to install twint, but I keep making the following errors:
"error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cchardet
      copying src/cchardet/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cchardet
      copying src/cchardet/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/cchardet
      running build_ext
      building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/cchardet
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/ext
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/ext/uchardet
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/ext/uchardet/src
      creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/ext/uchardet/src/LangModels
      aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC -Isrc/ext/uchardet/src -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c src/cchardet/_cchardet.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/src/cchardet/_cchardet.o
      src/cchardet/_cchardet.cpp:196:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
        196 |   #include "longintrepr.h"
            |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cchardet
  Running setup.py clean for cchardet
Failed to build cchardet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cchardet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"


What command are you using to install?

"--break-system-packages"

twint supports Python 3.6 - 3.8. You may have to use a supported Python version and install twint by running pip install twint or pip3 install twint.
You can find other installation options for this package on PyPi.

I still got the error but twint is installed

What command did you run? And what error did you get? Did you downgrade your Python as suggested?

I rain "pip3 install twint"  but I had to use "--breaks-systems-packages" or else I would get another error. I tried upgrading pip3 but I got another error

The error:   "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for upgrade"

Did you try downgrading python as suggested? You are using Python 3.12 but the package supports 3.6-3.8

Can you give me an example?

I am getting the following error "Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'" and I even used this command "sudo apt install python3.6 -y"

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549829/how-do-i-downgrade-my-version-of-python-from-3-7-5-to-3-6-5-on-ubuntu

I am getting the following error Unable to locate package python3.7-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7-dev'
E: Unable to locate package python3.7-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7-venv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7-venv'

How do I upgrade to newer version?

Not sure I understand you... What do you want to upgrade?

I want python3.7 so how do I upgrade to that?

Moving from python 3.12 to 3.7 is a downgrade not upgrade.  You have to use pyenv https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/
